# Проблема с циклом for и поиском значений Nan

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Нужно загрузить из таблицы данные и удалить столбцы, которые содержат значение Nan. Вот мой код:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

data = pandas.read_csv('TrueOrFalse.csv')

X = np.array([data['1'], data['2'], data['3'], data['4']])

for i in X[2]:
    if np.isnan(X[2][i]) == 'true':
        X[0][i] = X[0][i+1]
        X[1][i] = X[1][i+1]
        X[2][i] = X[2][i+1]
        X[3][i] = X[3][i+1]
    else:
        i += 1
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-70-d2187077755d> in <module>()
         11 
         12 for i in X[2]:
    ---> 13     if np.isnan(X[2][i]) == 'true':
         14         X[0][i] = X[0][i+1]
         15         X[1][i] = X[1][i+1]

    IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

**Решение:** `data = data.dropna()`. Через цикл можно и не перебирать массив, легче загрузить данные из заранее отсортированного DataFrame.

Comment: Можете `TrueOrFalse.csv` куда-нибудь выгрузить и ссылку дать?

Comment: Почему вы результат вызова `isnan` сравниваете со строкой?

Comment: Таблицу к сожелению не могу выгрузить

Comment: Точно! Хорошо, что вы увидели ошибку. Спасибо, исправил)

Comment: Ещё подозреваю, что вы в `i` ожидали не значение, а индекс элемента в массиве, то есть имели в виду `for i in range(len(X[2]))` (но не знаю, работает ли это с numpy, не пробовал)

Comment: @AndreyStebenkov, как правило у каждого вопроса может быть несколько ответов (причем правильных). Поэтому даже если вы нашли подходящее решение, нельзя сказать, что вопрос "закрыт" или "решён". Лучше добавить свое решение в качестве отдельного ответа.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему это можно сделать более элегантно:

```
data = pandas.read_csv('TrueOrFalse.csv')
data = data.loc[:, data.notnull().all()]
```

В результате все столбцы содержащие хотя бы один `NaN` будут удалены

Comment: Красиво и элегантно, но мне нужно использовать массив далее в `DecisionTreeClassifier()`

Comment: `DecisionTreeClassifier` как и большинство методов SKLearn замечательно работают напрямую с Pandas DataFrame's... ;-) Если все-таки нужен `Numpy array`, то `data.values` - вернет соответствующий Numpy array